# Calling a list of operators from a handler

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, operator

I have a collection of addons that sometimes contain/handle additional data that I can't (or sometimes don't want to) save inside blender as custom properties.

So I thought I'd make a helper addon that will call a certain operator from each other addon and each addon will check itself what needs to be saved/loaded.

So far I have this:

```
def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.save_post.append(save_load_persistant.SavePersistentData)
```

as a handler and this is an example of one of the other addon's "save" operator:

```
class X_percistency_save(Operator):
    bl_idname = "percistency_save.X_volume"
    bl_label = "Saves X during ""save file"""
    def execute(self, context):
        if some_internal_check:
            path = bpy.data.filepath[:-6] + "_Xdata.raw"
            print("Saving X to: ", path)
            return {'FINISHED'}
        return {'None'}
```

This operator can of course be called via `bpy.ops.percistency_save.X_volume()`. But since there is an unknown number of Operators from an unknown number of other addons to be called, I thought the best way would be to just iterate over all operators I write into this specific operator group ("percistency_save").

Sadly my first instinct doesn't work:

```
for operator in bpy.ops.percistency_save:
     operator()
```

Since:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'BPyOpsSubMod' object is not iterable
```

Is there a way you can see to achieve something similarly modular without having to curate an explicit list of operators?